# How can I link a participant's response to a question to a subsequent question on Qualtrics?

Tags: linker, qualtrics

I am trying to find out whether I can do this on Qualtrics. Essentially I want to have a block with one question like this:

- Please write a list of up to 5 people in your household with whom you talk at least once a week:

1.__
2.__
3.__
4.__
5.__

Then, I want to link the Response they gave in each row to a set of questions in the following module:

Think about *1.*, how often do you talk to *1.*?

For example, if the participant answered:

1. Anne
2. Sally

I would like to then have personalized questions asking:

Think about [Anne], how often do you talk to [Anne]?
Think about [Sally], how often do you talk to [Sally]?

I don't know if this is possible at all on Qualtrics. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Pipe the answers from your first question into the subsequent questions.  When you create/edit your follow-up questions click on the "Piped text" tab and select the previous question to insert the piped text into your question.